# Updating embedded Map entries in Mongo using Morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

We have a collection which stores a Map as an `embedded` collection. We need to update fields within individual entries of the Map.

Is there any way to do that?

```
@Embedded
private Map<String, MyClass> map = new HashMap<String, MyClass>();
```

we want to update fields inside the `map` which match a given key. We are using `Morphia` in our `Daos`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an update in Morphia to do this. You will have to use dot-notation to specify the path including the map key.

Comment: Do you have an example? that doesn't actually make a very clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. You'll find an example here: http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Updating under subtitle set/unset. The example uses a List but the same applies for Maps.